# Why is the Simplified CommonJS Wrapper syntax not working on my Dojo AMD module?

Tags: javascript, dojo, js-amd

Im starting to sort of wrap my head around requirejs and the new Dojo AMD structure, but I have a problem with some early tests:

cg/signup.js:

```
define(['dojo/_base/fx', 'dojo/dom'], function(fx, dom){    
    return function(){
        this.hidePreloader = function(id){
            var preloader = dom.byId(id);
            fx.fadeOut({node : preloader}).play()
        }
    }
})
```

This works fine.  In the master cg.js file:

```
require(['dojo/_base/kernel', 'dojo/_base/loader'])
dojo.registerModulePath('cg', '../cg')

require(['cg/signup', 'dojo/domReady!'], function(Signup){
        var sp = new Signup();
        sp.hidePreloader('preloader')
})
```

Bam. Done. However, in using the Simplified CommonJS Wrapper structure:

```
define(function(require){    
    var fx = require('dojo/_base/fx'),
        dom = require('dojo/dom');

    return function(){
        this.hidePreloader = function(id){
            var preloader = dom.byId(id);
            fx.fadeOut({node : preloader}).play()
        }
    }
})
```

I get an undefinedModule error.  It seems to come from the `dojo/_base/fx` line, but I don't know why.

**UPDATE**

For clarification.

*index.html scripts*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug:true,async:true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cg.js"></script>
```

*cg.js*

```
require(['dojo/_base/kernel', 'dojo/_base/loader'])
dojo.registerModulePath('cg', '../cg')

require(['cg/signup', 'dojo/domReady!'], function(signup){
    signup.testFunc()
})
```

*js/cg/signup.js*

```
define(['require', 'exports'], function(require, exports){
    var dom = require('dojo/_base/kernel');
// Any other require() declarations (with very very few exceptions like 'dojo/_base/array throw undefinedModule errors!!!

    // without any error causing requires, this works fine.
    exports.testFunc = function(){
        alert("hello")
    }
})
```

Comment: Hmm, a slightly different variation seems to work on JSFiddle. (But I can't link to it right now since JSFiddle is in read-only mode.) Could you give more details on the exact error?

Comment: That's the exact error.  By using the Simplified CommonJS Wrapper technique with the same paths and the same require statements, the console prints an error `undefinedModule`.  I have `isDebug=true` in the script config and `debugAtAllCosts` doesn't throw anything more.  What's the variation that's working for you?

Comment: I can't separate into multiple files on JSFiddle so I tried `define("foo", function (require) { ... })` where the `...` contains your require statements, plus `console.log`s for the `fx` and `dom` objects. Two crazy-looking objects got logged to the console... Dojo 1.7.1?

Comment: Hmm... I can't seem to get anything besides a few modules in _base to load.  `dojo/_base/kernel` and `dojo/_base/array` work, but many other's I've tried throw `undefinedModule` errors.  Is this a path issue?  I'm following as much reference material as I can find to a T and it just isn't working.

Comment: Also, with the first "name" parameter (where foo is in your example), then the resulting object is `3`, and therefore has no properties. Without that parameter, I at least have access to the `exports`.

Comment: Dojo 1.8.3, I am almost always getting undefinedModule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dojo completely supports the Simplified CommonJS Wrapper format.  however, there is a precondition... you must have no dependencies array.

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var fx = require('dojo/_base/fx'),
        dom = require('dojo/dom');

    // continue...
});
```

this will NOT work the same

```
define(['require', 'exports', 'module'], function (require, exports, module) {
    var fx = require('dojo/_base/fx'),
        dom = require('dojo/dom');

    // continue...
});
```

nor will this...

```
// in this case require, exports and module will not even exist
define([], function (require, exports, module) {
        var fx = require('dojo/_base/fx'),
        dom = require('dojo/dom');

    // continue...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the addition to this conversation, I will have to open that project back up and do some more testing.  It's an interesting caveat, do you know more about why?

Comment: it's done this way because to support this format, the function body needs to be scanned for usage(s) of `require(...)` and that adds some overhead.  in order to avoid that overhead where it's not needed, you need to "signal" to the loader that you are (or are not depending on your perspective) using this format.  the "signal" that you are using this format is having no dependencies array - which is why an empty dependencies array is different to not having one at all.

Comment: I tried this simple example in dojo 1.8.3 and it did not work at all.

Comment: were you using dojo from source or from a build/CDN?  the default build options strip out the code that supports this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little wrapper around Dojo define that uses code taken from RequireJS to calculate the dependencies based on the toString of the definition function. It wraps the current "define" in the global namespace, calculates the dependencies and then call's the wrapped define.

defineWrapper.js:

```
// Workaround for the fact that Dojo AMD does not support the Simplified CommonJS Wrapper module definition
(function() {
    var commentRegExp = /(\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\/|([^:]|^)\/\/(.*)$)/mg,
      cjsRequireRegExp = /require\(\s*["']([^'"\s]+)["']\s*\)/g,
      ostring = Object.prototype.toString;
    function isArray(it) {
      return ostring.call(it) === '[object Array]';
    }
    function isFunction(it) {
      return ostring.call(it) === '[object Function]';
    }
    var oldDefine = define;

    define = function(name, deps, callback) {
        //Allow for anonymous functions
        if (typeof name !== 'string') {
          //Adjust args appropriately
          callback = deps;
          deps = name;
          name = null;
        }

        //This module may not have dependencies
        if (!isArray(deps)) {
          callback = deps;
          deps = [];
        }

        //If no name, and callback is a function, then figure out if it a
        //CommonJS thing with dependencies.
        if (!deps.length && isFunction(callback)) {
          //Remove comments from the callback string,
          //look for require calls, and pull them into the dependencies,
          //but only if there are function args.
          if (callback.length) {
              callback
                  .toString()
                  .replace(commentRegExp, '')
                  .replace(cjsRequireRegExp, function(match, dep) {
                      deps.push(dep);
                  });

              //May be a CommonJS thing even without require calls, but still
              //could use exports, and module. Avoid doing exports and module
              //work though if it just needs require.
              //REQUIRES the function to expect the CommonJS variables in the
              //order listed below.
              deps = (callback.length === 1 ? ['require'] :
                  ['require', 'exports', 'module']).concat(deps);
          }
        }

        if(name === null) {
            return oldDefine(deps, callback);
        } else {
            return oldDefine(name, deps, callback);
        }
    }
})();
```

How would you use it?

```
<script src="...dojo..."></script>
<script src="defineWrapper.js"></script>
<script>require(["some_simplified_commonjs_defined_module"], function(module) {
   // use module here
});</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that Dojo does not support the simplified CommonJS style for dependency detection when doing a build.  This means you'll either need to use the normal dependency list style, or you'll have to duplicate all your dependencies when defining layers in the build profile.

Here's the relevant bug in their tracker:

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15350

Comment: as of dojo 1.9.0 this is now supported in the build

Answer (score 1):

is `require` defined?   I don't see where that argument value would come from. I think you might have to do something like

```
define(["require"], function(require){ ...
```

Comment: No, it works with `dojo/_base/kernel` but not `dojo/_base/fx`, so require is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I started to think that maybe I wasn't meant to learn Dojo. But, it all comes together with a little more reading. I'm not sure exactly what I did different or whatever, but here's the working layout.

*index.html scripts and config*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojoConfig = {
    async : true,
    isDebug : true,
    debugAtAllCosts : true,
    packages : [{
        name : 'cg',
        location : '/../js/cg'
    }]
}
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cg.js"></script>
```

*js/cg.js*

```
require(['cg/signup', 'dojo/ready'], function(signup){
    signup.init('preloader')
})
```

*js/cg/signup.js*

```
define(['dojo', 'require'], function(dojo, require){
    var fx = require('dojo/_base/fx')

    return new function(){    
        this.init = function(id){
            fx.fadeOut({node : dojo.byId(id)}).play()
        }
    }
})
```

Again, not entirely sure why the `var fx = require(...)` statement works differently in this one than the others, could be the build I downloaded vs. the CDN, who cares. It works.  Some links I used to help for others possibly in the same boat:

[Writing Modular JS](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/)

[AMD vs CommonJS Wrapper](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define)

[Dojo Toolkit AMD](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd)

[Dojo Config (1.7)](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/dojo_config/)